# "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: registry, python

Good morning! 
OS: Win7
Language: Python2.7.14

Problem:I am attempting to convert a REG_BINARY type (value: DefaultGatewayMac 00 50 56 fb 29 e0) from "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\Unmanaged\" to Hexadecimal format using the following loop in the function below:

```
def regbin2hexaddr(regval):
 addr = ''
 for val in regval:
  addr + '_x '% ord(val)
 addr = addr.strip(" ").replace(" ",":")[0:17]
 return addr
```

However, I have received the following TypeError

`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

I assume the correction may be related to the usage of strings and int utilizing the %. Please advise, thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you think `%` is supposed to be doing in the code?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, the '%' is an operator used for string formatting.

Comment: Yes, *I* know what it is. But do ***you*** know what it is?

Comment: Oh... so `addr + '_x '% ord(val)` should be this; `addr + '_x %d' % ord(val)`.

Comment: UPDATE: Incorrectly using the '%' operator was the mistake, tested this with the above change and the function now works correctly. Thank you to Ignacio for the question. Appreciate it. Have a great day.